# Not getting output with cycle tag in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying my hand on cycle tag of django, but when i use the below code the output is not as expected
```

```
<style>
   .row1{
     color:blue;
   }
   .row2 {
      color:green;
   }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> this is a world</h1>
    <p> which is {{ html_temp }}</p>
    <p>
        {% for o in list %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
            {{ o }}</br>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
</body>
```

```

I got the output as black text instead of colored text because I make the classes row1 and row2 as blue and green respectively. where I am getting it wrong?

Comment: whats it showing when you do **inspect element** on the html page from your browser

Comment: Note, your HTML is badly broken; you can't put text directly inside a `tr`, you need to have at least one `td`; and you should have a `table` surrounding the rows. Are you sure you didn't mean just `div` instead?

Comment: Chaning `tr` to `td` will solve the problem...